# Tips for implementing an existing codebase in Gazebo?

Tags: ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys, I understand this is a general question I am just looking for direction while also not violating an NDA. As the title states, how should I go about implementing an existing codebase for a robot into Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19753/tips-for-implementing-an-existing-codebase-in-gazebo?/) by [MRhinelander](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5614/mrhinelander/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-18**:
Can you be just a tiny bit more specific? Is the codebase in C++? What do you need from simulation?

**Comment by [MRhinelander](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5614/mrhinelander/) on 2018-06-19**:
Yes I apologize its a broad question. The codebase for the actual machine is in C++, I need to use that code in my simulation. I already created a model and a diff drive system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Interfacing with Gazebo can be done through C++ plugins or through the Gazebo transport system. I believe in your case you'll want to implement some model / world plugin which connects to the rest of your codebase. Read about plugins [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_hello_world&cat=write_plugin).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MRhinelander](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5614/mrhinelander/) on 2018-06-25**:
I am having trouble grasping the concept of connecting a plugin to an existing codebase. I can write my own plugins, and I can modify and understand my codebase. Just not sure how to connect them.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-25**:
You'll probably need to compile the plugin linking and including both Gazebo and your code...